# how to refresh listView from its adapter

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

What would be the best way to refresh the `ListView` from its `BaseAdapter`? I am having a `ListView` that has an adapter. Here one of the views has a button that when the user clicks I would like to refresh a certain view (at position).

I have tried calling the following code in `public View getView(int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent)`, but this doesn't work.

```
View attendingUsers = parent.getChildAt(11);
attendingUsers.invalidate();
```

Is there a way to redraw the view?

Comment: ListView doesnt support single row update.. 
for Single update you need to use RecyclerView

Comment: is there then a way to refresh the whole list from the adapter ?

Comment: call otifyDataSetChanged() after updating the list

Comment: oh didn't realise i can call this inside the adapter, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `notifyDataSetChanged();` solved my problem

Answer (score -1):

**This will work only for RecyclerView and not for ListView**.
Use notifyItemChanged (int position, Object payload) it is much more efficient, for more information:
[notifyItemChanged reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())